# How to read local file when there is no internet connection on flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

I've implemented a ListView that loads a Json from internet. So far so good.
But I'd like to read a local file in case that attempt to read the online json fails.

I have an async method that reads either a json from internet or from a local asset:

```
Future<List<Post>> getPosts(String urlJsonInternet, String fileJsonLocal) async {

  //read json from internet
  await http.get(urlJsonInternet).then((responseInternet) {

      //If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON
      return _buildPostList(responseInternet.body);

  }).catchError((onError) {

     //read json from local file
     rootBundle.loadString(fileJsonLocal).then((responseLocal) {
        return _buildPostList(responseLocal);
     });

  });

}
```

*_buildPostList it's just a method that parses the json.*

To test it I turned off the network at the Android Emulator.

What is happening is that nothing is returned to the Snapshot at FutureBuilder. It seems like something related to the execution order of the process.

This is the screenshot of the exception: https://ibb.co/iMSRsJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making wrong use of `asnyc` `await` and *promises*. When using `await`, you should not use `then` because they do exactly the same. Check [this out](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling) for reference on `Future`'s.

You are also *returning* from the *wrong scope*, i.e. both of your `return`'s return to the *callbacks* and not to your function *getPosts*. I will rewrite `getPosts` with `async await` and `try catch`.

Lines after `await` only get executed once the `Future` is finished. [More on that here](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures).

```
Future<List<Post>> getPosts(String urlJsonInternet, String fileJsonLocal) async {
  try {
    //read json from internet
    final responseInternet = await http.get(urlJsonInternet);

    //If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON
    return _buildPostList(responseInternet.body);
  } catch (e) {
    //read json from local file
    final responseLocal = await rootBundle.loadString(fileJsonLocal);

    return _buildPostList(responseLocal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I'm a flutter newbie, thanks for your help.

Comment: How we can check if internet is available ? so we can do network calls after that.